# Unable to call an REST API for FileUpload in php

Tags: php, rest, api

There is an API build in C# and i am successfully able to to call that api from postman but the same thing i want to do with php.

**Postman**

Header info need to set before call api
[image]

Actual File Upload in attachment parameter. 
[image]

Using Postman Tool I am able to upload file successfully.

But The Problem is Same thing i want to do using php Code.

**What I Tried in PHP CODE:**

```
$headers = array('DistributorCode:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_DISTRIBUTORAPIKEY'],'FolderName:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_DISTRIBUTORAPIKEY']);

$this->CallRestAPI('POST', 'http://192.168.1.55/api/upload' , array('attachment'=> file_get_contents(REPORTPATH . $_SERVER['HTTP_DISTRIBUTORAPIKEY'] . "\\07122017163625.zip")), $headers);


function CallRestAPI($method, $url, $data , $headers) {
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        switch ($method) {
            case "GET":
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
                break;
            case "POST":
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
                break;
            case "PUT":
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
                break;
            case "DELETE":
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                break;
        }
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        echo "Response:".$response;die;

        /* Check for 404 (file not found). */
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        // Check the HTTP Status code
        switch ($httpCode) {
            case 200:
                $error_status = "200: Success";
                return ($data);
                break;
            case 404:
                $error_status = "404: API Not found";
                break;
            case 500:
                $error_status = "500: servers replied with an error.";
                break;
            case 502:
                $error_status = "502: servers may be down or being upgraded. Hopefully they'll be OK soon!";
                break;
            case 503:
                $error_status = "503: service unavailable. Hopefully they'll be OK soon!";
                break;
            default:
                $error_status = "Undocumented error: " . $httpCode . " : " . curl_error($curl);
                break;
        }
        curl_close($curl);
        echo $error_status;
        die;
    }
```

Comment: Whats the problem though? Does it give any of those errors? Which error, or any, or does it just sit dead?

Comment: "The Problem is Same thing i want to do ". "I want to" is not a problem, it's a statement of requirement. What's the actual issue?

Comment: it returns blank screen

Comment: @ADyson: I already tried something to achieve required output but fail to do that.

Comment: yes I can see that. But "it fails" is not a problem statement either. What goes wrong with your code? Errors? Unexpected behavior? Give us a clue. We're not mind-readers. Consider if _you_ were trying to answer this question. Would you have enough info? If not, then think about what you'd want to know in order to help, and then provide that. You have enough rep points to know what a good question looks like, I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the code from postman on the top right corner. The "code" button. It generates the code any language what you want.

[image: the code button]
[image: you should choose curl then you can copy the code]

Comment: Its Amazing, I was not aware about this hidden feature of Postman, thanks Hakan SONMEZ